# Best way to forward user to another page?

Tags: php, javascript

I have items displayed that has a countdown timer, and there are "coming soon" items which are to be displayed as well once the previous items' time has ended. My problem now is, I need to redirect the coming soon items' page to the order form page once they are available for buying.

What I am thinking is, redirect the user to the order page if they refresh the item's page? How to do that? I think it's not advisable to use

```
meta refresh
```

right?

Comment: Please write descriptive titles

Comment: ajax better than meta refresh

Answer (score 3):

Meta refreshing is not the nicest way to do it - since you need to be checking a condition first.

Since you are using php, why not check at the beginning of the item page whether the user should be redirected to the order page?

Like so:

```
<?php
  if(true){ //Check if available for buying
    header('Location:order.php');
    exit;
  }
  //rest of your code stays...
?>
```